# Getting ActiveSupport::Duration error for sidekiq after upgrading sidekiq from 6.x to 7.x version and rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-7

recently I have upgraded rails from **5.2** to **7.x** and ruby **2.6** to **2.7.x** and encouthering an issue with sidekiq job execution.

Getting `ActiveSupport::Duration` as an error message for any **perform_later**

I tried various ways to fix the issue but was struck to figure out the exact area of the failure. It perfectly works with Rails 7.x and ruby 2.7 with sidekiq 6.x version and fails only on the **sidekiq 7.x** version, so it seems like any API modification but failing to figure it.

**Version details**

```
Rails 7.0.4.2
ruby 2.7.7
Redis 5.0.6
sidekiq 7.0.6
```

Comment: Think you need Redis 6.2+ https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/main/docs/7.0-Upgrade.md

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and for me, it turned out to be a breaking change that I wasn't handling.  I had

```
SIDEKIQ_STATUS_EXPIRATION = 48.hours
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: Rails.application.secrets.redis_url }
    Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware(config, 
               expiration: SIDEKIQ_STATUS_EXPIRATION)
end
```

The first line was the object that was of type ActiveSupport::Duration.  Changing that line to be an integer instead made the error disappear.

```
SIDEKIQ_STATUS_EXPIRATION = 48.hours.to_i
```

Comment: This fixed the "ActiveSupport::Duration" bug, thank you! Now I am getting redis-client errors and Redis < 6 errors, which I assume are blockers until I switch from the app from the redis gem to the redis-client gem

Answer (score 1):

@mike-perham here is a simple example, it looks like it is related to the sidekiq status gem:

```
Ruby 3.2.1
Rails 7.0.4.3
Sidekiq 7.0.7
Redis 5.0.6 (gem)
sidekiq-status 3.0.1

class TestJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  def perform()
  end
end

TestJob.perform_async()

/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.14.0/lib/redis_client/command_builder.rb:37:in `block in generate': Unsupported command argument type: ActiveSupport::Duration (TypeError)

            raise TypeError, "Unsupported command argument type: #{element.class}"
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed on main, see issue 5806.

Comment: I am still seeing this exact error when calling perform_async after upgrading to Sidekiq 7. Using: Sidekiq 7.0.7, Rails 7.0.4.3, Latest Redis gem version 5.0.6 and Ruby 3.2.1.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I haven't switched to redis-client gem to access Redis 6.2+?

Comment: @noob Thanks but it seems like switching from **redis** to **redis-client** is huge because both have different implementations. have u tried to switch?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Redis version. It would help if you'd show the full backtrace of the error.